# Python Model with ReferenceProperty and join table

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I believe this is trival but fairly new to Python.

I am trying to create a model using google app engine.

Basically from a E/R point of view 
I have 2 objects with a join table (the join table captures the point in time of the join)
Something like this

```
Person      | Idea     | Person_Idea
-------------------------------
person.key   idea.key    person.key
                         idea.key
                         date_of_idea
```

my Python code would look like

```
class Person (db.Model):
  #some properties here....

class Idea(db.Model):
  #some properties here....

class IdeaCreated(db.Model):
  person= db.ReferenceProperty(Person)
  idea= db.ReferenceProperty(Idea)
  created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

What I want to be able to do is have a convient way to get all ideas a person has (bypass idea created objects) -sometimes I will need the list of ideas directly.

The only way I can think to do this is to add the follow method on the User class

```
def allIdeas(self):
  ideas = []
  for ideacreated in self.ideacreated_set:
     ideas.append(ideacreated.idea)
  return ideas
```

Is this the only way to do this? I is there a nicer way that I am missing?

Also assuming I could have a GQL and bypass hydrating the ideaCreated instances (not sure the exact syntax) but putting a GQL query smells wrong to me.

Comment: Please consider using `ndb`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use the person as an ancestor/parent for the idea.

```
idea = Idea(parent=some_person, other_field=field_value).put()
```

then you can query all ideas where some_person is the ancestor

```
persons_ideas = Idea.all().ancestor(some_person_key).fetch(1000)
```

the ancestor key will be included in the `Idea` entities key and you won't be able to change that the ancestor once the entity is created.

i highly suggest you to use `ndb` instead of `db` https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/

with `ndb` you could even use `StructuredProperty` or `LocalStructuredProperty`
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured

**EDIT:**
if you need a many to many relationship look in to ListProperties and store the Persons keys in that property. then you can query for all Ideas with that Key in that property.

```
class Idea(db.Model):
    person = db.StringListProperty()

idea = Idea(person = [str(person.key())], ....).put()
```

add another person to the idea

```
idea.person.append(str(another_person.key())).put()

ideas = Idea.filter(person=str(person.key())).fetch(1000)
```

look into https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#ListProperty

Comment: Ah thats cool, umm maybe I am missing something, but with this approach, how do I also capture the 'when the relationship' is created i.e. date_of_idea

Comment: can't see anything related to that in the question. do you mean ordering the query by the creation date? you would need to order (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_order) the query, if thats what you mean.

Comment: not sure what you mean by `capture` but a `fetch` returns the whole entity with all its properties.

Comment: Sorry, I mean if the Idea is a child of the parent, it's not going to work for my data model (I think) my model has many to many relationship between idea and person with the addition of capturing when the relationship is made. The ancestor approach would only work for a one to many right?